# Select Newest Instead of Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have a stored procedure that returns data from a database table that is populated from an API. The current query is:

```
Select * 
From Inventory 
where StockNumber in (select distinct stocknumber)
order by Make
```

Instead of this I actually need to take the top 1 newest record based on a `DateTimeStamp` column as there are often many records with the same stocknumber but different timestamp.

Comment: `ORDER BY DateTimeStamp DESC LIMIT 1`?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server)?

Comment: Sql Server Latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a correlated subquery:

```
Select i.*
From Inventory i
where i.datetime in (select max(i2.datetime)
                     from Inventory i2
                     where i2.stocknumber = i.stocknumber
                    )
order by i.Make;
```

Another method is to use the ANSI standard window function `row_number()`:

```
select i.*
from (select i.*,
             row_number() over (partition by stocknumber order by datetime desc) as seqnum
      from Inventory i
     ) i
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INNER JOIN` clause:

```
Select t1.* From Inventory t1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT StockNumber, MAX(Make) AS Make FROM Inventory GROUP BY StockNumber) t2
ON t1.StockNumber = t2.StockNumber AND t1.Make = t2.Make
```

Comment: What if there are multiple t1.Make = t2.Make?

Comment: Because you are using a max() and a group by in t2 (the subquery which is named t1 above by accident) will only ever return 1 row. If there are multiple t1's you will have the t2 entry repeated for each of them

Comment: @StanislavL If exist, then he must decide which one to be reserved. So in this condition, maybe another `JOIN` criteria should be there.